# CSS bubble error box for a form

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I want to create an error box for a form like the one below. 
[image]

I already themed the input box and am using jQuery validation to display errors. However I can't get that error box right. I think I'll need to put that together with three tags, but I don't know what tags to use (jQuery validation uses a `label` tag to display the error).
My current code for the error is:

```
<label for="email">
  <span>Email:</span>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="error">
  <label for="email" class="error" style="">Az e-mail címet kötelező megadni</label>
</label>
```

I must make this IE7 compatible.

I made the following changes:

```
  <div class="dataline">
  <div class="label">Label:</div>
  <div class="field"><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <label class="error">Error text</label>
  <div class="ender"></div>
  </div>
```

I set the arrowhead as an image for the class `arrow` so now it looks perfect. Basicly I used 4 left floated block elements (label, input, arrowhead and bubble body). Now I only have two problems: the arrowhead is displayed even when there's no error. How can I hide it when the `label` is not after it? My other problem is that the container `div` is 800px wide and if the error text is long, it wraps around to the next line. How can I avoid it?

My css is:

```
    div.dataline {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 3000px;
    owerflow: visible;
    height: 60px;
}

div.field {
    float: left;
}

div.label {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

div.arrow {
    background-image: url('gfx/redarrow.png');    
    margin: 7px 0 0 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
}

div.ender {
    background-image: url('gfx/bubbleend.png');    
    margin: 7px 0 0 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 3px;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
}

label.error {    
    height: 27px;
    background-image: url('gfx/bubblemiddle.png');
    float: left;    
    padding: 9px;
    margin: 7px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add at least your CSS so we can help you

Comment: Now I solved the problem of long error message. I posted the CSS. My only problem is now that the arrow always appears, and I need to hide it if there's no error for that particular line.